# Did WhatsApp Desktop stop supporting making calls, View Once, and Disappearing Messages?

Tags: windows-10, whatsapp

In v2.2243.11.0 under Windows 10 22H2, suddenly if someone calls in, the Desktop **completely ignores it**. And if I try to make calls myself, **clicking the buttons does nothing**:

[image: Unclickable buttons]

The About section's **Disappearing messages is always unclickable**, and the **View Once** option is not even presented when using photos.

[image: Unclickable Disappearing messages]

[image: No View Once]

Last but not least, there's no central setting for a **default timer**.

Any idea what happened? Does it happen to others as well?

Neither resetting nor re-uninstalling helped.

P.S.

I manually gave WhatsApp Microphone/Camera permissions after noticing they got changed to off:

[image: WhatsApp permissions]

Comment: This question (per its tag) is about WhatsApp for Desktop, not WhatsApp Web (which has its own tag and never had call abilities).

Comment: My bad, I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: No, the former is an app from Microsoft/Mac Store while the latter is just a website. This means the latter is portable and works instantly anywhere, but it lacks basic features such as link previews and calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems v2.2244.7.0 brought back call support (and a later version also brought it back for groups).

**Update:** Then 1 year later v2.2345.6.0 finally brought **View Once** support (see screenshow below)! This is even though it's weirdly (secretly) [**still** officially unsupported](https://faq.whatsapp.com/578442220724722/?helpref=hc_fnav&cms_platform=windows-desktop) (also see similar [**official** web version announcement](https://faq.whatsapp.com/578442220724722/?helpref=hc_fnav&cms_platform=web), in which it really does still not work).

As for the **disappearing messages** setting being unclickable and no **default timer** anywhere, there is a hidden (as in not linked from the general FAQ) [**official** statement announcing lack of support for this](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5590979194321336/?helpref=hc_fnav&cms_platform=windows-desktop).

[image: View Once in Desktop App]